# Calculating percentage from row vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a table that has 4 rows: Item Name, Item Cost Price, Item Sell Price & Item Percent. What I am trying to do is calculate the percentage from the Item Cost Price and Item Sell Price and display in in the 'Item Percent' Column.
Please see my current code below:

```
    <b-col sm="6" lg="9">
  <b-card no-body>
    <b-tabs pills card>
      <b-tab title="Standard" active>
        <template>
          <b-table class="mb-0" responsive="sm" hover striped :items="filtered.products" :fields="columns"></b-table>
        </template>
      </b-tab>
      <b-tab title="Standard w. %">
        <template>
          <b-table class="mb-0" responsive="sm" hover striped :items="filtered.products">
            <template slot="percentage" slot-scope="data">
              {{(products.sellPrice - products.costPrice / product.sellPrice).toFixed(2) + '%'}}
            </template>
          </b-table>
        </template>
    </b-tabs>
  </b-card>
</b-col>
```

Please let me know if you require more of my code

Comment: Just add number to this line `{{(products.sellPrice - products.costPrice / product.sellPrice).toFixed(2) + '%'}}` so it becomes `{{Number((products.sellPrice - products.costPrice / product.sellPrice).toFixed(2)) + '%'}}`

Comment: @MohamedNidabdella thanks for your help, I did end up doing something along the lines of what you have mentioned. Will dig up the code and post the answer shortly.

Comment: @TomDickson And what is the answer?